# Cordova InAppBrowser Refresh button in toolbar

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova's InAppBrowser and loading a remote page in the webview. 
I want to hide the location bar but yet still show a refresh button.

I tried to enable toolbar as below, but it doesn't show the refresh button.

toolbar sample
[image]

```
var ref2 = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(REMOTE_URL_HERE, '_blank', 'toolbar=yes');
```

any idea how to add a refresh button to the bottom toolbar?